# Embedding a theme within a Vaadin portlet

Tags: themes, portlet, vaadin

How can I embed a theme within a Vaadin portlet ?

I created a theme as [described here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html#figure.themes.theme-contents) but at runtime, when I check the HTML source with Firebug, the theme's style returns a 404 error.

How can I include a theme in my portlet correctly ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In Liferay, Vaadin themes must locate a folder under the portal context. For example, Liferay bundled with Tomcat, the default location is:

```
LIFERAY_HOME/tomcat-6.0.29/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN/themes
```

For more information take a loot at [Book of Vaadin, Section 12.5](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.liferay.widgetsets.html).

Answer (score 1):

Henri Kerola's answer is correct but leaves out a very irritating pitfall. Your next question on stack overflow will likely be: Why isn't my CSS updating even though I put my new theme in

```
<LIFERAY_HOME>/<TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps/ROOT/html/VAADIN/themes
```

It's important to know that Liferay 6.1 Caches css from themes in

```
<TOMCAT_FOLDER>/temp/liferay/css/portal/html/VAADIN/themes/<THEME_NAME>/styles.css_E_DATA
```

So if you want to change the theme in a deployed instance you need to delete the cached version, otherwise you will spend hours and hours playing with firebug and fiddler and other tools trying to figure out why you are getting the old theme.

Edit: You can also put liferay in developer mode which prevents the caching, which is even better... just pass this in to the java process running your liferay

```
-Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties
```